# batch split note scans with automatic recognition of parts in page

Tags: imagemagick, scanning, document-management, pim

I regularly use paper to make notes and concepts for most things, work and others. To be quick when having an idea I note them one after another, just to make sure I find things later, I use paper with a sidebar where I add some short tags. On top also the current date.

I am now in the process of making them accessible digitally. First step was obviously scanning them. (stored in folder per month)

Now I want to push them in some content system.

I need now a way, semiautomagically

- view page by page
- computer checks for horizontal lines or part of lines and set sections.
- I control and correct
- computer recognizes tags in sidebar, I correct if necessary
- image is cut in parts
- The parts are saved by tags (and maybe date, at least keep the month)

I like to ask for suggestions for tools I could play with, a kind of gui for imagemagick crop in the most simple case. Of course I could code such tool quite easily but I thought I ask here first, often you guys have awesome ideas.

Comment: Some of your criteria is very specific and quite broad - it is going to be hard to answer your question. I think if you can code it easily (assuming with OCR / line detection capabilities) then go for it although I don't think any one can code things like that easily - or have I miss-understood your question.

Comment: Hm yeah I admit doing recognition will be hard, I might have some gui to choose the height of cropping manually. I had a look into gimp interactive batch mode. Might be a way to go?